# Error when trying install mod_wsgi using pip

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

When trying to install mod_wsgi using pip as follows:

```
pip install mod_wsgi
```

I get the following error:

> 4m.so -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python3.4/config-3.4m
>   -lpython3.4m
>       /bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.4m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when
>   making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>       /usr/local/lib/libpython3.4m.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
>       collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> Command "/usr/local/virtualenvironment/bin/python3 -u -c "import
>   setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-install-dgfnrl36/mod-wsgi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /tmp/pip-record-m7uwmjt6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/virtualenvironment/include/site/python3.4/mod-wsgi" failed
>   with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-dgfnrl36/mod-wsgi/

I am using Python 3.4.3. I even tried to build mod_wsgi from source and pretty much get the same error.

From seeing this in the following in the stack trace perhaps its looking for python source or other source? I'm still fiddling around trying to figure out what it wants but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I have a quite similar problem.  The only difference is that I use python3.6 and I would like to add the corresponding mod_wsgi. I obtain the very same error messages.

Comment: Hi @LajosSoukup , I actually managed to solve everything by building from source. Il add the answer here in a couple of hours, just need to re-vist my notes

Comment: @LajosSoukup whats the output of pip -V

Comment: Hi @De An:   Thank you for the advice. After installing the python3.6-dev libraries I was also able to compile  a new mod_wsgi from source and to install it.   The key was to use the   --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.6 parameter in the "configure" script.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to build mod_wsgi from source after installing the python dev libraries.

So

```
yum install python3-devel
```

1. Download desired mod_wsgi version from http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/
2. Unzip the source and cd into the unzipped source folder
3. execute the following `./configure --with-python=/path/to/python/executable`
4. `make`
5. `make install`

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to install the module in my virtual environment.
You got this error because you did not install your python with --enable-shared.
Here is the link that talks about this issue
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/S9D2cTefj4k

and here is the link show you how to install python from source code as a shared library

https://danieleriksson.net/2017/02/08/how-to-install-latest-python-on-centos/